# Selecting Distinct Entries across columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database that tracks the prizes that people win across the booths of a fair. Most of the booths have overlapping and similar prizes, so a participant can win a Pillow (for example) from 2 booths.

Now, we want to be able to track how many people won a given prize, since we want to tally and account how many people won a certain prize already.

Here is how the table looks like:

[image: table]

It's easy to get the count of a certain prize in a given column. However, I'm having problems trying to consolidate the data across multiple columns.

Comment: Can you clarify which of these rows should and which should not occur? What exactly is the condition for an entry to be distinct?

Comment: All of the rows should occur, and they're distinct based on the ID. In this case, the distinct count for id `1` should be 4, id `2` should also be 4, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't normalize your table, a bunch of `union all`s could do the trick:

```
SELECT   prize, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT station_1_prize AS prize FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT station_2_prize AS prize FROM mytable
          UNION ALL
          -- Etc...
         ) t
GROUP BY prize
```